# How to use conv2d_transpose of Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Does anyone know how I can use the `conv2d_transpose` from keras found in this link: https://keras.io/backend/#conv2d_transpose ?

Could you explain to me what each parameter of this function does and how it works internally (what algorithm does it use, etc)? because I'm still a bit confused about how it works.

I'm wanting to enlarge an image as part of the process of a convolutional neural network. For example :

```
x.shape = (4,4,3)
```

That is to say it has 4 lines 4 columns and 3 channels. I would like to increase x to an array of (16,16,3) and to give a print in the matrix soon after the function (if it is possible), that is:

```
output = conv2d_transpose(x,....)
print(output)
```

Comment: You probably want the Conv2DTranspose layer: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose

Comment: yes, it's right. I will read  about Conv2DTranspose layer.